# Loadrunner and parameterize file upload

Tags: file-handling, loadrunner

I have my vugen script like this: `ITEMDATA,
"Name=File", "Value=C:\\testdata\\readme1.txt",`
and I want to parametrrize the `readme.txt` part of the script with a unique filename for each vuser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename information is simply a string.   You should be able to parameterize it like any other string, such as

```
ITEMDATA, "Name=File", "Value={myfilename}",
```

or

```
char myfilename[120]
...
sprintf(  myfilename,
          "Value=C:\\testdata\\%s",
          lr_eval_string("{readfromafileparameterfilename}") );
...
ITEMDATA, "Name=File", myfilename,
```